# 3 Column setup CSS problems

Tags: html, css

Hello I am trying to setup three 3 columns using the code below

```
<div class="col1"></div>
<div class="col2"></div>
<div class="col3"></div>

**CSS**

.col1 {
    background-color: #ddf;
    float: left;
    }
    .col2 {
    background-color: #dfd;
    float: none;
    }
    .col3 {
    background-color: #fdd;
    float: right;
}
```

But I cannot get it working if you take a look http://paycoinfaucet.cf/test/
You see the last column doesn't align with the other two

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting every div as inline-block with 33% of width, the divs will resize with the page.

```
.col1 {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 33%;   
    background-color: #ddf;
}
.col2 {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 33%; 
    background-color: #dfd;
}
.col3 {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 33%; 
    background-color: #fdd;
}
```

I suggest you to take a look at [bootstrap rows](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html)

```
<row>
 <div class="col1 col-md-4"></div>
 <div class="col2 col-md-4"></div>
 <div class="col3 col-md-4"></div>
</row>
```

This solution doesn't require additional CSS, and you can customize the size of your divs according to the size of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

set the width to each div :

```
.col1 {
    background-color: #ddf;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    }
    .col2 {
    background-color: #dfd;
    float: left;
    width: 447px;
    }
    .col3 {
    background-color: #fdd;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
```

and float them all to the left